# Firebase --> post test run generated test_result_1.xml seems to be broken

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-test-lab

We have a POC of running tests on the Firebase devices cloud and in the last few days I see weirdly formatted test_result_1.xml files that are generated after the test is concluded.
It used to be formatted as a JUnit XML file but now the content wildly differs from run to run. Sometimes, it's empty and sometimes it includes a content of an error that happened in one of our tests.
Did anybody encounter such behaviour? I can't seem to find a way to contact their support for assistance with this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try posting this to the #test-lab channel in the Firebase Slack forums. https://firebase.community/